# Unable to push structure in an array dynamically

Tags: arrays, struct

I have a election contract as follows:

```
contract election{
            struct Candidate{
            uint id_db;
            string name;
            string party;
            string election_sign;
            }
        Candidate[10][] public candidates;   //row for election region and cols for actual candidates.
        function addCandidate(uint _id, string memory _name) public{
            candidates[0].push( Candidate(1,"Sam", "", "halo") );
        }
        
   }
```

I am getting the following error:

```
contracts/election1.sol:60:9: TypeError: Member "push" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in struct ElectionContract.Candidate storage ref[10] storage ref.
    candidates[0].push( Candidate(1,"sdfuru", "", "halo") );
    ^----------------^
```

If possible I would like to know the process of adding candidates in two dimensional array dynamically.

Comment: Can you describe the intention of the line `Candidate[10][] public candidates;`? You want an array of an array of 10 candidates?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
candidates.push( Candidate(1,"Sam", "", "halo") );
```

Insteade of :

```
candidates[0].push( Candidate(1,"Sam", "", "halo") );
```

Comment: Still got the Same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
Candidate[10][] public candidates;   //row for election region and cols for actual candidates.
    function addCandidate(uint _id, string memory _name, Candidate memory c) public{
        candidates[1][1] = c;
    }
```

Comment: I want to add  candidates dynamically. We might not know the number in advance.

Comment: use a variable that will hold the index instead of "1" then.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code as follow:

```
Candidate[10] public candidates;   //row for election region and cols for actual candidates.
        
    function addCandidate(uint _id, string memory _name) public{
        candidates[0] = Candidate(1,"Sam", "", "halo") ;
    }
```

Removing [] after Candidate[10] and then assigning the struct to the array with =.